# Pass parameter into chrome.commands

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am attempting to make a simple extension to add the selected word to an array, and display it.

Everything works, but I am now trying to add a keyboard shortcut to do the same thing as right clicking > clicking my extensions icon.

I don't understand how to use the chrome.commands function to add the selected text to the array.

This is what I have in my background page:

```
var Words = []
...
function addToArray(info, tab) {
    var text = info.selectionText;
    Words.push(text);
}
```

and my chrome.commads listener:

```
 chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(info, tab) {
        addToArray(info, tab); // When I press keyboard shortcut, the word 'undefined' is added to the array...?
    });
```

When I press the shortcut, something goes wrong, because I get 'undefined' in my array, but I don't know what! There is no error in the console on the background page.

Could someone please help me with this problem? Thanks.

Obviously, the chrome.commands listener is working because I get undefined, but also, if I put `alert('test')` in it, the alert does show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short, you can't.**

As noted in [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands#event-onCommand), the callback of onCommand only gets the name of the command triggered.

So, to get a selection, you need to query for it yourself somehow from the listener:

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
    var tab = tabs[0]; // Got the tab
    // execute a content script to get the selection, for instance
    // You will need the "activeTab" permission
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(
      tab.id,
      {code: "getSelection().toString();"},
      function(results){
        Words.push(results[0]);
      }
    );
  });
});
```